# JSON loop within a loop to render parent and child elements with Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, foreach

I am trying to create a user interface based on my response from the server. I need to loop to get the about of tabs to create then loop to get the about of content to put inside the tabs. I get the right amount of tabs but not the right amount of inputs. My JSON is as such:

```
{
    "data": {
        "APIVersion": "2.0",
        "toplevelcontainer": [
            {"label": "value1", "type": "tabs", "key": "value1", "tooltip": "value1", "defaultValue": "value1",
               "content" : {
                    "innercontent": [
                        {"label": "tab1", "type": "input", "key": "value1","tooltip": "value1","defaultValue": "value1"},
                        {"label": "tab1", "type": "input", "key": "value1","tooltip": "value1","defaultValue": "value1"},
                        {"label": "tab1", "type": "input", "key": "value1","tooltip": "value1","defaultValue": "value1"},
                        {"label": "tab1", "type": "input", "key": "value1","tooltip": "value1","defaultValue": "value1"}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {"label": "value2", "type": "tabs", "key": "value2", "tooltip": "value2", "defaultValue": "value2",
                "content" : {
                    "innercontent": [
                        {"label": "tab2", "type": "input", "key": "value2","tooltip": "value2","defaultValue": "value2"}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {"label": "value3", "type": "tabs", "key": "value3","tooltip": "value3","defaultValue": "value3",
                "content" : {
                    "innercontent": [
                        {"label": "tab2",  "type": "input", "key": "value2","tooltip": "value2","defaultValue": "value2"}
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now my question is should I use angular.forEach or ng-repeat? My forEach loop looks as such:

```
angular.forEach(data.data, function(top) {
  $scope.containers = top;
    angular.forEach(data.data.toplevelcontainer, function(lower) {
        $scope.inputs = lower;
    })
});
```

UPDATE: with ng-repeat method
app.controller('TabController', function($scope, $http){

```
$http.get('data.json')
.success(function(data) {
    $scope.containers = data.data.toplevelcontainer;
    $scope.inputs = data.data.toplevelcontainer.content; //do I need to create a scope variable for each of these items I want to insert into the DOM?
})
```

Comment: that foreach loop is overwriting variables in every iteration. Should be able to use `ng-repeat` to create your tabs and content...not sure why you need to count them first

Comment: I'm not sure that I do need a for each. Do I have to create $scope.variable for each item I want to insert?

Comment: assuming it all flows from data shown...probably not

Comment: You can directly iterate over using ng-repeat

Comment: I updated my post does this http.get look plausible?

Comment: ya but $scope.inputs= data.data.toplevelcontainer.content will do

Comment: no because content is nested in arrays of tabs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a very primitive working tab system using the data provided.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.model = {};// add model properties to this object to prevent child scope issues

  $http.get('data.json').then(function(resp) {
    $scope.data = resp.data.data
  })
});
```

HTML

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="tab in data.toplevelcontainer" ng-click="model.activeTab=tab">{{tab.label}} - Click me</li>
</ul>
<!-- Content-->  
<div ng-repeat="tab in data.toplevelcontainer" ng-if="model.activeTab == tab">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="sub_tab in tab.content.innercontent">{{sub_tab.label}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZKzbhGqLtpDyUZRLFQ0?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: charlietfl can you elaborate on the reason you used `$scope.model = {}` ?

Comment: I used a very simple clcik event to set `activeTab` but `ng-repeat` creates child scopes...so by adding the `model` object it assures inheritance to all the child scopes. This is a fundamental problem that a lot of people learning angular run into

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to create variables on the scope to use nested ng-repeat. You can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data.toplevelcontainer">
    {{item.label}}
    <div ng-repeat="content in item.content.innercontent">
        {{content.label}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But, where do 'item' and 'content' get declared?

Comment: They are declared in a new scope created by the ng-repeat directive. Think of it like a for each loop: foreach (var item in data.toplevelcontainer) { ... }